# sqlplus oracle11g why is sequence.nextval automatically incrementing the value when i call it for the first time?

Tags: sql, oracle11g, sqlplus

I feel like i'm going insane here is the table parameters

```
CREATE TABLE member(
member_id number(4,0) not null,
first_name varchar2(25) not null,
last_name varchar2(25) not null,
street varchar2(25) not null,
city varchar2(15) not null,
phone char(11) not null,
valid_date date not null,
balance number not null,
constraint member_pk PRIMARY KEY(member_id));
```

The sequence statement

```
CREATE SEQUENCE member_seq
START WITH 110
INCREMENT BY 1
MinValue 110
MaxValue 999
Nocycle
Cache 50;
```

My first insert statement for the table

```
INSERT INTO member
VALUES(member_seq.nextval, 'JACK', 'WHITE', '123 MAIN ROAD', 'RALEIGH', '919-7763838', '01-JAN-99', 0);
```

When i run the select statement to check the insertion the sequence member_id value is 111 and not 110, i redid the whole thing trying to call currval first and it cant work because you cant call currval until you initialize the sequence, please help.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably, it doesn't really matter.  You're using a sequence to generate the keys because you don't actually care what the values are or whether there are gaps just that the values are unique.  If that's not the case, you've got a different set of problems.

What is `deferred_segment_creation` set to?  My guess is that it's set to `true` so the segment isn't created when the table is created.  It's created when the subsequent `insert` is run which internally causes Oracle to rollback the initial `insert`, create the segment, and then re-execute the `insert` which calls `nextval` a second time.  If that's the case, you can force the segment to be created when the table is created

```
CREATE TABLE member(
    member_id number(4,0) not null,
    first_name varchar2(25) not null,
    last_name varchar2(25) not null,
    street varchar2(25) not null,
    city varchar2(15) not null,
    phone char(11) not null,
    valid_date date not null,
    balance number not null,
    constraint member_pk PRIMARY KEY(member_id)
 )
 segment creation immediate;
```

Comment: its for a class proj / final lab. he shows a select statement of the table and the parameters for the sequence but yet this problem seems to happen. We were definitely not taught anything segment creation so I guess ill add a comment about this hoping he understands. Thank you so much for your reply! Glad its not something simple I missed because i researched heavily before posting.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly -

You should not use `select member_seq.nextval from dual ;` for checking the current sequence number. Oracle internally increases the number to next. Sequence number gets exhausted. [Even though you did not execute `COMMIT` in the session]

Use can also use below query to check current value

```
SELECT last_number
  FROM all_sequences
 WHERE sequence_owner = '<sequence owner>'
   AND sequence_name = '<sequence_name>';
```

After running insert :

1. you can check in your table `select  member_id from member`
2. you can query  `select member_seq.currval from dual ;` This will give your current value.

> After running create table, create sequence and insert. Run below queries you will get fair idea.
>
> ```
> select member_id from member;
> MEMBER_ID
> ----------
>    110
>
> select member_seq.currval from dual ;
> CURRVAL
> ----------
>    110
>
> select member_seq.nextval from dual ; -- increments to next value 
> CURRVAL
> ----------
>    111
>
> select member_seq.currval from dual ; -- Since you ran nextval above, sequence incremented 
> CURRVAL
> ----------
>    111
> ```